# I can't find python skier images

Tags: python

Can you tell me how to find images that I have to use when I make python skier game?Like skier.down.png,skier.right1.png...I can't find it with Google.

Answer (score 0):

From this blog, http://joecrippscoding.blogspot.com/2014/11/skier-game.html:

> Skier Game Download the code and images from this link, you need
>   pygame also. https://www.dropbox.com/s/a65peogbsk803a8/Skier.zip?dl=0

I downloaded and verified there are 8 images:

skier_flag.png
skier_right1.png
skier_crash.png
skier_left1.png
skier_right2.png
skier_down.png
skier_left2.png
skier_tree.png